# Simplest data-binding for button onClick in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to migrate a desktop app from WinForms, and I was testing out the @bind tags with a simple app.

1. Type your name into the input.
2. Click the submit button.
3. Print the input on the screen.

The key is that I didn't want to save the input until the OnClick submit event. I'm trying to do this with just one property, but unfortunately all I can get is this.

```html
<div class="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Two variable method data-binding.</h4>
        <label for="username">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" @bind-value="@name" />
        <button id="submitName" class="btn-primary" @onclick="SetName">Submit!</button>
        <small class="@Collapse">Your name is @Name.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

```cs
@code {
    private string name;
    private string Name { get; set; } = null;
    private string Collapse { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) ? null : "collapse"; } }

    void SetName()
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The input element has to be bound to a field `name` which changes on every `onChange` event. Feels wasteful. Ideally, I'd like to remove field `name` and `SetName()` from `@code`, but can't seem to figure out a way to do that without JSInterop. Can I sent `bind-value="name"` to only bind on submit or similar?

Comment: [Polite] Why is this a problem?  You're setting a field in the class, you aren't saving anything until you commit it to storage which you do as part of the submit process.

Comment: That's a fair question. I think my chief concern is of wasted latency on Blazor server-side: I don't need the server to commit every change to ```name```, because I don't care about the input until I click ```submitName```. With JS, this is trivial, since there is no binding - you use ```$('#username')```to get the input value and send it back to the server.

Comment: Assuming you have any validation, it needs to be sent to the server to do that. This is just how blazor server works normally with default binding (I think I understand what you're asking?) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I understand that. All I want to do is to register the ```bind-{attribute}:event``` under a different DOM object property other than it's own. Right now, ```@bind-value="@name"``` is shorthand for ```@bind-value="@name" @bind-value:event="onChanged"```. All I want is to define, ```@bind-value=@Name @bind-value:event="submitName:onClick"``` if that makes sense.

Comment: You can't avoid the execution of the change event on the server. This is the essence of Blazor Server App: Code is executed on the server, and not on the browser. You can shift to WebAssembly, in which case, the code is executed on the client (browser)... still binding involves raising events, which by the way, you can control and prevent from re-rendering your components, till a given timing, but does not have the overheads of executing the code on the server.

Comment: As per the above comments.  It's built in, accept it.  It only updates when you exit the control.  You need it to happen to track edit state on the form and say prevent users exiting the form.  A lot of very clever people write this code, so I don't think it's a problem.  My one piece of advice is, DON'T try and change the behaviour with some JS code, you will almost certainly shoot yourself in the foot!

Comment: [Polite] I wrote this comment in June 2021. I both agree and disagree with you.  Disagree - A lot of clever people did write Blazor and you are likely to shoot yourself in the foot trying to do JS stuff on inputs (unless you really know what you are doing).  Agree - there's some cumbersome stuff in Blazor.  I no longer use the whole EditContext/InputBase concept for editing [it's not fit for purpose]. I don't even use `ComponentBase` as my base component any more [It a fat bloated piece of code that eats CPU cycles and memory].

Comment: I think that many of those "very clever people" wish they could start again with a clean slate but with the experience and knowledge they now have.  We can, they are stuck with some of the decisions they made at the time because there's an awful lot of code that depends on it!